# cut function for to label out-of-tolerance parameter values

Tags: r, cut

For a process parameter, there are upper and low limits. When the data is collected and stored in a vector, I try to use the `cut` function to recode the vector.

There is how I did it (as an example):

```
x = mtcars$mpg

cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf,20, 30, Inf), labels = c("low","good","high"))
```

This works beautifully.

But when I tried to label too high and too low values as just a "failure", there is a error message:

```
x = mtcars$mpg

cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf,20, 30, Inf), labels = c("failure","pass","failure"))

Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : factor level [3] is duplicated
```

Obviously `cut` function does not expect us to provide repetitive labels.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Note that from R version 3.5.0 duplicated factor labels are permitted so you shouldn't encounter this issue on an up-to-date install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using `cut` one option is to change the `levels` after `cut`

```
x1 <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf,20, 30, Inf), labels = c("low","good","high"))
levels(x1) <- c("failure","pass","failure")
```

---

However, instead of `cut` you can use simple `ifelse`

```
ifelse(x >= 20 & x <= 30, "pass", "failure")
```

Or just

```
c("failure", "pass")[(x >= 20 & x <= 30) + 1]
```

---

Or if there are multiple conidtions to check we can use `case_when` from `dplyr` where we can add conditions if required.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(mpg >= 20 & mpg <= 30 ~ "pass", 
                            TRUE ~ "failure"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the way you had it working with `cut`,  you can just recode the values.

```
x = mtcars$mpg
F1 = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf,20, 30, Inf), labels = c("low","good","high"))
F2 = factor(ifelse(F1=="good", "pass", "failure"))
```